# How does Rails perform SQL queries for multiple requests to one model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Not sure if I'm reading Puma logs right. So I'd like to clarify three things:

***First***

If in controller we do something like:

```
def find_user
  user = User.where(name: "Alex")
  @user = user.where(age: 25)
end
```

How many sql queries are made?

***Second***

```
def find_user
  user = User.where(name: "Alex")
  @user = user
end
```

The same question.

***Third***

```
def find_user
  user = User.find(1).id
  @user = User.find(1).first_name
end
```

The same question.

Comment: First and second: one or zero queries (depends on usage of `@user` variable). Third: Two queries.

Comment: Is it possible to perform zero queries when we use 'where'?

Comment: Of course, why not? If you, for example, set `@user` variable as relation (as you do it in this example) and didn't use it anywhere in your controller and view, you'd have 0 DB queries generated.

So technically speaking, both first and second `find_user` methods generate 0 database queries. Any query _may_ be generated if you use `@user` variable or the return value of `find_user` method (which is the same thing, obviously).

Comment: @MarekLipka I thought queries are made regargless to usage of their results.

Comment: Well they aren't. `ActiveRecord` uses lazy evaluation of the queries, so they are performed by the time you _need_ their results. You can be misguided by the console output, where all of these `where` calls generate SQL query, but it's only because under the hood the console calls `inspect` on every evaluated value, to generate output, and that's where `ActiveRecord` gets the message, 'oh, I need to actually perform DB operation to get the results needed'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's awesome!

Comment: I decided that my comments deserve expanding to a full answer. :)

Comment: @MarekLipka Sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the third piece of code generate 2 DB queries, the first and second, technically speaking, generate 0. Any query *may* be generated if you use `@user` variable or the return value of `find_user` method (which is the same thing, obviously).

The reason behind this behavior is that `ActiveRecord` uses lazy evaluation of the queries, so they are performed by the time you need their results.

You can often be misguided by the console output, where all of these where calls, if you execute them one by one, generate SQL query, but it's only because under the hood the console calls `inspect` on every evaluated value, to generate output, and that's where `ActiveRecord` gets the message, 'oh, I need to actually perform DB operation to get the results needed'. Consider this example, you can check it in your console:

```
lambda do
  user = User.where(name: "Alex")
  @user = user.where(age: 25)
  return 'any other value'
end.call
```

You'll get the `'any other value'` string returned from this lambda expression, but guess what - the `@user` variable will be set to hold `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance and there would be 0 DB queries generated.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord no SQL query will be made until you use ActiveRecord's object to fetch some record or execute some operation which will effect your DB.

So in first case there will be only 1 query to database same as second case. But in third case if you are using both `user` and `@user` to fetch record then two queries will be fired as both are different object. If you use only `@user` then only one query will be fired